# How to center an image on Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

On my `BitBucket` wiki repository I've uploaded an image, now I'm trying to center it:

```
![Alt text](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/MVC-Process.png/220px-MVC-Process.png)|
```

I tried to put around this: `<div align="center">my image</div>`

but I can't center the image on `Bitbucket`, someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

You can not center an image on bitbucket because the platform doesn't support arbitrary HTML in Markdown.

See link : https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo

Comment: This hasn't changed even after 5 years. Like every other offering from Atlassian, Bitbucket is absolute trash